# Routing type doesn't change to "browserHistory" even after setting history attribute while using react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm working on basic reactJs application with routes. By default ReactJs uses `hashHistory` type of history to maintain history of URLs visited by the user. Here is my `package.json` file having version of all the dependencies I'm using:

```
{
  "name": "scotch-cars",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "learning routing in reactJs",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "webpack -d --watch",
    "build": "webpack",
    "serve" : "serve ./public"
  },
  "author": "Rasik Bihari",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "serve": "^5.2.2",
    "webpack": "^2.6.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-router": "^1.0.3"
  }
}
```

Here is my `index.jsx` file which is the starting point:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute,browserHistory} from 'react-router';
import Main from './common/main.component.jsx'
import Home from './common/home.component.jsx'
import About from './common/about.component.jsx'
import Car from './car/car.component.jsx'

render(
    <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={Main} history={browserHistory} >
            <IndexRoute component={Home} />
            <Route path="/cars" component={Car}/>
            <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
        </Route>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

As you can see in the code snippet above I've set `history={browserHistory}`. But as soon as my dev server starts and I browse the home path then reactJs is still appending hashes at the end of the URL (shown in yellow) which means it is using `hashHistory` type of history.

[image]

Can someone point out the mistake here?

Here is my `webpack.config.js` which loads the `index.jsx` file shown above:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
console.log(__dirname);
var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public');
console.log(BUILD_DIR);
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');
console.log(APP_DIR);

var config = {
  entry: APP_DIR + '/index.jsx',
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },

  module : {
    loaders : [
      {
        test : /\.jsx?/,
        include : APP_DIR,
        loader : 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Here is the `public/index.html` file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!--Stylesheet-->
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
        <base href="/">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--Container for React rendering-->
        <div id="container"></div>
        <!--Bundled file-->
        <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Code for `./common/main.component.jsx`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Main extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <nav className="navbar navbar-default">
                    <div className="container-fluid">
                        <div className="navbar-header">
                            <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">Scotch Cars</a>
                        </div>
                        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                            <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li className="active"><a href="#">Link <span className="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
                <div className="container">
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Main
```

**Update 1**: Moving the `history={browserHistory}` attribute from `Route` tag to `Router` tag has no effect on the desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

History object is not given to the `Route` but the `Router`

This should work

```
 <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Main}  >
        <IndexRoute component={Home} />
        <Route path="/cars" component={Car}/>
        <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
    </Route>
</Router>,
```

Also upgrade to a higher version of React router at least to v2.0.0.

You can do that by deleting the entry for `react-router` in package.json and then installing it as

```
npm install -S react-router@2.0.0
```

However, if you are just kickstarting you app, you should go with the latest version of `react-router.` i.e. `v4.1.1`

Below is the training doc for configuring the same : https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter

Comment: I made this change but no luck. I'm still seeing hashes at the end of the url being loaded in the browser.

Comment: Can you upgrade your router version to atleast v2.0.0, by deleting the entry in package.json and then running `npm install -S react-router@2.0.0`

Comment: Yep. Sorted! this worked after upgrading `react-router` package version to 2.0.0. Can you please add this suggestion as well in the post itself before I mark it as accepted.

Comment: Btw, starting v4.x "react-router" has changed a lot. There is a new `BrowserRouter` tag. That's why I initially started with latest version only but then downgraded to v1.x just to learn the basics first. My above router configuration present in `index.jsx` will not work in v4.x of "react-router" package. Thanks for extending all the help.

Comment: Well yes, it has changed a lot. But its better to start with the latest, even if you face some challenges, I know you above config doesn't work with latest version